# Open downloaded file automatically

Tags: javascript, html

Chrome remote desktop has a great setup experience

You click a button to download a file and when it is finished, it has an accept & install button that opens the file.

It shows a dialog like this:

[image: Allow chrome remote desktop to open chromeremotedesktophost.msi]

It also knows if you cancel or delete the download like this:

[image]

And it knows when the file is finished downloading

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since to use "Chrome remote desktop" you have to download its `chrome extension` it can use the `extension APIs` to access the downloads.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads